# gtest: run TEST_P inside 2 TEST_Fs

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17, googletest

I have three tests:

```
TEST_F(lexer, no_data)
{
    // some initial test
}

INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P(parser, lexer, ::testing::Values(/*some list of values*/));
TEST_P(lexer, with_data)
{
    // fixture's static member initialization.
    // tests for each input value
}

TEST_F(lexer, no_more_data)
{
    // final test
}
```

The problem is that when I'm running test it runs `TEST_F`s at the beginning and then runs `TEST_P`, but I need to run first `TEST_F`, then `TEST_P`s for each input and finally the latest `TEST_F`. 
Note: In the fixture I have a static member which is used in all testcases, but I need to have the member uninitialized when running first `TEST_F`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: You cannot. And you should not.

Slightly longer answer:
Having your tests depend on each other (or their order of execution) is a **very bad idea** - for that very reason googletest (and the google test adapter for visual studio) even provide the option to *shuffle* your test case execution order, so in each test run you get a new order, just to catch bugs that would be hidden otherwise, e.g.

Test case #2 covers function `Foo()` which should (among other things) set the global flag `Bar` to `true`.
You check that state of `Bar` at the end of the test, which is `true` and the test passes.

Test case #5 covers function `Baz()` which should (among other things) also set the global flag `Bar` to `true`. However, `Baz()` has a bug, and does **not** do this. 
You check that state of `Bar` at the end of the test... which is `true` since it was already set in test case #2, and the test passes - you **failed** to detect the bug.

Make sure that each of your test cases can run **independently** from each other.